# how to use scala spray detach?

Tags: scala, akka, spray

i'm trying to use spray detach as following:

```
path("") {
  get {
    detach {
      respondWithMediaType(`text/html`) { // XML is marshalled to `text/xml` by default, so we simply override here
        complete {
          <html>
            <body>
              <h1>Say hello to <i>spray-routing</i> on <i>Jetty</i>!</h1>
            </body>
          </html>
        }

      }
    }
  }
}
```

but i get following compilation error:

> type mismatch;  found   : spray.routing.RequestContext => Unit 
>   required: spray.routing.directives.DetachMagnet
>             respondWithMediaType(`text/html`) { // XML is marshalled to `text/xml` by default, so we simply override here
>                                               ^

I looked at: https://github.com/spray/spray/wiki/Detach and I still have no idea what i'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at a deprecated documentation. If you to want to read the current documentation you have to look at the [spray.io](http://spray.io/) website.

Regarding your problem, the current documentation specifies a different signature for the `detach` directive - [see here](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.0/spray-routing/execution-directives/detach/#detach)

```
def detach()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Directive0
def detach()(implicit refFactory: ActorRefFactory): Directive0
def detach(ec: ExecutionContext): Directive0
```

As you are passing your ExecutionContext implicitly I guess, you have to write the parenthesis:

```
detach() {
  respondWithMediaType(`text/html`) { // XML is marshalled to `text/xml` by default, so we simply override here
    complete { ...
```