# Spray's `detach` Directive

Tags: scala, spray

Given the following Spray code:

```
object Main extends App with SimpleRoutingApp {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("my-system")

  val pipeline: HttpRequest => Future[String] = sendReceive ~> unmarshal[String]

  startServer(interface = "localhost", port = 8080) {
    path("go") {
      get { 
        detach() { 
          complete {
            val req = Post("http://www.google.com") ~> addHeader("Foo", "bar")
            pipeline(req).recoverWith[String]{ case _ => Future { "error!" } }
          }
        }
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

I put the `complete` function within the [detach](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/execution-directives/detach/) directive.

The docs explain that **detach** will: `execute the inner route inside a future.`

What's the significance of using (or not) `detach` - from a **performance** perspective?

I looked at this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937119/how-to-use-scala-spray-detach), but it focuses on how to use detach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`detach` is usually needed because routing runs synchronously in an actor. This means that while an `HttpRequest` is routed, the actor cannot process any other messages at the same time.

However, routing bits that are asynchronous like completing with a `Future` or using one of the `FutureDirectives` will also free the original routing actor for new requests.

So, in cases where routing itself is the bottleneck or you complete a request synchronously, adding `detach` may help. In your case above, you already complete with a `Future` and have a relatively simple routing structure in which case adding `detach` won't help much (or may even introduce a tiny bit of latency).

Also, `detach` comes with some inconsistencies you can read about here:

- https://github.com/spray/spray/issues/717
- https://github.com/spray/spray/issues/872

An alternative to using `detach` is using per-request-actors.

In akka-http, routing is implemented on top of Futures to be as asynchronous as possible and not confined to an actor any more so that `detach` isn't needed and was removed therefore.

Comment: Trying to understand your first few sentences - will not using `detach` and calling `Await.result` inside of the `route` result in only a single HTTP Request being handled at a time, i.e. simultaneously by the web app?

Comment: To answer here as well: yes, that's true. If there are no asynchronous directives used, blocking in the route structure will prevent asynchronous route processing.

Comment: Thanks! I only posted that Google groups link since others will find your post there helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Without detach spray will process all requests one by one, while with detach it'll process them parallel. If you can process this requests in parallel, you'd better use detach for better performance.

Comment: You're saying that, without `detach`, the spray web-server will process HTTP requests one at a time, i.e. it can't handle more than 1 request simultaneously? Could you please provide a source?