# Understanding Spray's detach directive

Tags: scala, future, spray

I'm trying to understand Spray's detach directive and whether there's any difference between using detach and using the onComplete directive. What I want to achieve is "one thread per request" where by thread I mean JVM thread ( which should be an OS thread).

So, what the difference between A and B ?

**Method A:**

```
// assume controller.divide(a,b) returns Future[Int]  

val route =
  path("divide" / IntNumber / IntNumber) { (a, b) =>
    onComplete(controller.divide(a, b)) {
      case Success(value) => complete(s"The result was $value")
      case Failure(ex)    => complete(InternalServerError, s"An error occurred: ${ex.getMessage}")
    }
  }
```

**Method B:**

```
// assume controller.divide(a,b) returns Int
val route = {
    path("divide" / IntNumber / IntNumber) { (a,b) => 
      detach(global) {
          Try { controller.divide(a,b) } match {
              case Success(value) => complete(s"The result was $value")
              case Failure(ex) => complete(InternalServerError, s"An error occurred: ${ex.getMessage}")
          }
      }
} }
```

Cheers !

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31364405/sprays-detach-directive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of `detach` is that you don't need your method to return a `Future` - that's really it.

The idea is to run items you know won't throw exceptions compactly, but without needing to block the handler thread. You should rewrite **Method B** as:

```
detach(global) {
  complete(s"The result was ${controller.divide(a, b)}")
}
```

In the spray-routing world, the `Failure` case would be handled by an outer [`handleExceptions`](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.3/spray-routing/execution-directives/handleExceptions/#handleexceptions) directive.

Comment: and with this a new thread is spawned to execute divide(a,b) ? Cheers !

Comment: It's going to be run in `global`, the execution context you've provided (or the implicit execution context in-scope, if you don't explicitly provide one). Typically, execution contexts manage their own thread pools, and may or may not spawn a new thread immediately.

Answer (score 0):

See [Spray's `detach` Directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31364405/sprays-detach-directive) where the **accepted** answer explains very well, what

- detach does and
- how it uncouples from the route executing actor.