# Parallel execution of methods

Tags: scala, spray, spray-routing

I have an application that sends multiple request to my `spray-can 1.3.1` server.

FireBug shows me, that these requests are triggered in parallel.

However, on the server these request are handled strictly serially.

I think I need to somehow configure the spray server to handle multiple requests in parallel - but how?

The server is started like that:

```
object Server extends SimpleRoutingApp{  
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val system = ActorSystem()
    startServer("0.0.0.0", port = 8080) {
      get{
        pathSingleSlash {
          complete{
            HttpEntity(
              MediaTypes.`text/html`,
              Template.txt
            )
....
```

Comment: Why do you think that requests are handled sequentially on server? What's your akka configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Spray routing is synchronous in an actor, you will need to do something else to make it handle multiple requests in parallel.

1. Using the [`Detach` directive](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/execution-directives/detach/): This directive will spawn a new actor to process that request.
2. Using an [actor-per-request](https://github.com/NET-A-PORTER/spray-actor-per-request)

You can also find [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31382500/702002) [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937119/how-to-use-scala-spray-detach) in SO about it.